# How to convert text to table or .csv from webservice request in Python

Tags: python, sql, web-services, beautifulsoup

I imported requests and Beautifulsoup4 in python,and request xml from Web service.
This was what i did:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
session_request = requests.session()
response = session_requestion.post('',data='',headers='')
soup = bs(response.text,'lxml')
fruitresult = soup.find_all('getfruitbysql')

print(fruitresult)
```

Then, it show :

```
[<getresultbysql>
&lt;DataSet&gt;
&lt;Table&gt;
     &lt;Fruit&gt;Apple&lt;/Fruit&gt;
     &lt;NumberOf&gt;10&lt;/NumberOf&gt;
     &lt;Price&gt;12&lt;/Price&gt;
   &lt;/Table&gt;
   &lt;Table&gt;
     &lt;Fruit&gt;Banana&lt;/Fruit&gt;
     &lt;NumberOf&gt;18&lt;/NumberOf&gt;
     &lt;Price&gt;10&lt;/Price&gt;
   &lt;/Table&gt;   
&lt;/DataSet&gt;
</getresultbysql>]
```

How to transform this result to dataframe or .csv like below:

```
--------------------------
| Fruit | Number | Price |
--------------------------
| Apple |   10   |   12  |
| Banana|   18   |   10  |
--------------------------
```

Thanks a lot!..

Here is the whole xml response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<getresultbysqlResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<getresultbysql>
&lt;DataSet&gt;
&lt;Table&gt;
     &lt;Fruit&gt;Apple&lt;/Fruit&gt;
     &lt;NumberOf&gt;10&lt;/NumberOf&gt;
     &lt;Price&gt;12&lt;/Price&gt;
   &lt;/Table&gt;
   &lt;Table&gt;
     &lt;Fruit&gt;Banana&lt;/Fruit&gt;
     &lt;NumberOf&gt;18&lt;/NumberOf&gt;
     &lt;Price&gt;10&lt;/Price&gt;
   &lt;/Table&gt;   
&lt;/DataSet&gt;
</getresultbysql>
</getresultbysqlResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: provide the source of html .

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη ，okay.  I post it!!  thank for your attention.

Comment: what's the url? You also have a typo in your session object

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the `soup` object ready, you can try using `lxml` to extract the data:

```
from lxml import etree


xml_text = soup.find('getresultbysql').text
root = etree.fromstring(xml_text)

data = [['Fruit', 'Number', 'Price']]
for table in root.findall('Table'):
    data.append([i.text for i in table.getchildren()])
```

Here's the result:

```
╔════════╦════════╦═══════╗
║ Fruit  ║ Number ║ Price ║
╠════════╬════════╬═══════╣
║ Apple  ║     10 ║    12 ║
║ Banana ║     18 ║    10 ║
╚════════╩════════╩═══════╝
```